# How to avoid empty popups when GetFeatureInfo request is empty

Tags: openlayers, getfeatureinfo

I set up a WMS with QGIS SERVER. I am querying it via a web app based on OpenLayers.

Everytime I click on my map, I send a GetFeatureInfo to a specific layer passing the coordinates where I clicked, and the response is rendered in a popup. So far so good.

The problem is if I click where there's no layer's feature in the map, I'd like no popup to show up, but instead I get an "empty-table-response" from the WMS which is in turn rendered in my popup, and this is annoying.

Here is an example of a request with some interesting data:

https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=piste_sci&LAYERS=piste_sci&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=1164063.3256063634%2C5842307.561011146%2C1165993.360570564%2C5844237.595975346

And here is one with empty data which I don't want to display in the popup:

https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=piste_sci&LAYERS=piste_sci&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=1161292.4833310258,5842938.166494499,1163222.5182952264,5844868.201458699

This is how I am requesting the data in OL (only the relevant part):

```
function getInfoUrl(evt, view, lyr) {
    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    var url = CORS_PREFIX;
    var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    if (lyr.get('type') != 'base') {
        var visible = lyr.getVisible();
        if (visible) {
            url += lyr.get('source').getGetFeatureInfoUrl(evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857', {
                'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/xml'
            });
            return url;
        }
    }
}

map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        // display info in fancyAlert
        for (let i = 0; i < ol_layers.length; ++i) {
            let layer = ol_layers[i];
            let text = getInfoUrl(evt, view, layer);
            if (text) {

                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        fancyAlert(this.responseText, 'info', 'Layer Info');
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", text, true);
                xhttp.send();
            }
        }
    })
```

How should I avoid the second response to show up? I thought a request to an empty feature area should trigger no response or at least a WMS exception. Maybe this is not a standard but it's what I was used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not your own service it's unlikely you can change the output.  In that specific case you could check if the output contains at least two html tables before displaying it

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    if (this.responseText.indexOf('</TABLE>') != this.responseText.lastIndexOf('</TABLE>')) {
        fancyAlert(this.responseText, 'info', 'Layer Info');
    }
}
```

Comment: it is my service. In that case, is there an alternative? Anyway, your solution might be good enough, I'll test it asap and tell you if it works fine for my case.

Comment: It seems similar to other WMS have I checked.  Although the output varies between services it is always a status 200 response with valid html (typically comments and styles, but in your case a header table) and a client always needs to check if there is also displayable data embedded it to avoid an empty popup.